# MKMapView struggles with zero height constraint - edgeInsets of map view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, nslayoutconstraint

I have an `MKMapView` about 300 high which collapses between two other views, simply animating the height up and down as you'd usually do when collapsing a view.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet var heightMap: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var theMap: MKMapView!
```

When the view launches it is height zero..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ..
    heightMap.constant = 0
}
```

there's an infuriating warning...

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000904f0 MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093a60 UILayoutGuide:0x60800018fd80'Edge Insets'.top == MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.top + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093b50 UILayoutGuide:0x60800018fd80'Edge Insets'.bottom == MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093b50 UILayoutGuide:0x60800018fd80'Edge Insets'.bottom == MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.bottom   (active)>
```

Note that it seems to be struggling with "edgeInsets" or possibly "Edge Insets" (with a space!) top and bottom,

```
'Edge Insets'.top == MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.top + 8
'Edge Insets'.bottom == MKMapView:0x7fe6b3000600.bottom
```

Map views have a read-only property `.alignmentRectInsets`

(Actually when I print that out, whatever it is, it is zero anyway..

```
let ari = theMap.alignmentRectInsets
print("wth \(ari)")
> wth UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

)

I can't even find any info about "edge insets" on a MKMapView, what's the deal here?

I've carefully checked for not-installed constraints and the usual problems.

Comment: If you are giving the height constriant, no need of both bottom and top layout constraint. Try with deleting one of them.

Comment: hi @MBN - no, I am not adding the weird 'Edge Insets'.top and 'Edge Insets'.bottom constraints.  these seem to be added by MKMapKit itself.  (all of "my" constraints are perfect).

Comment: it's incredible nobody knows this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly I only get this error if the initial hieght is zero, so it seems to be an issue with the initial setup of the mapview.  The solution them seems to be to be

1. Give the mapView a hieght in the storyboard (I did 100)
2. Make
   the mapView hidden by checking the hidden box in interface builder

When its time to show the mapView:

1. Unhide it
2. Minimize it (I set the constant to .ulpOfOne instead of zero because technically frames are not supposed to be degenerate.)
3. Animate to the final position

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController{
       @IBOutlet weak var m: MKMapView!
       @IBOutlet weak var h: NSLayoutConstraint!
       @IBAction func t(_ sender: Any) {
           m.isHidden = false
           h.constant = .ulpOfOne
           view.layoutIfNeeded()
           h.constant = 100
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
               self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

FYI I would actually use a UIStackView for this and just animate isHidden instead and then you don't even have to deal with the constraint in code.

Comment: Hey Josh thanks. It does seem to be just a bug, or something. **"Edge Insets"** remains mysterious!  Your tip about **.ulpOfOne** is a good one, thanks.  The idea of just using a stack view for .isHidden is a good one, too!

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same issue and got this warning every time I wanted to hide a MKMapView (either manually with a height constraint or inside a UIStackView). I've noticed that I can prevent the warning by setting the map view's bounds height to 0 before activating the zero height constraint. So I wrote a little class to encapsulate the bug:

```
import MapKit

class HideableMapView: MKMapView {

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if self.containsZeroHeightConstraint() {
            // Set the bounds manually before the constraint gets processed to prevent an auto layout warning
            self.bounds.size.height = 0
        }

        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }

    private func containsZeroHeightConstraint() -> Bool {
        return (self.constraints.filter { $0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0 }).isEmpty == false
    }
}
```

This class worked for my project where MKMapView is embedded in a UIStackView. Depending on your setup you may have to override another method. Set a symbolic breakpoint for UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to view the call stack.

I've also filed a radar, which you can find here: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6109127172423680