# What is a Constraint in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting this error `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` with a bunch of logs below it (shown below). There is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353899/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-probably-at-least-one-of-the-const) attempting to solve it. But I'm not sure what a constraint is and I can't find any documentation on it's definition/diagrams.

Is there an explanation anywhere on what constraints are? This [documentation on NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint) is pretty dense and cryptic to me e.g. "constraint based layout system." An explanation would be super beneficial to help me debug this.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021777a0 UIView:0x7fe80893f840.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x7fe808939a90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002168780 'Mask_Trailing_Trailing' _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x7fe808939a90.trailing == BackButton.trailing   (active, names: BackButton:0x7fe808a18380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021688c0 'MaskEV_Leading_BIB_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fe80891d0c0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe80893f840]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002168fa0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x7fe80891d0c0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600003b61880'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002169040 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[BackButton]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b61260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active, names: BackButton:0x7fe808a18380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217f7a0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600003b61260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fe808b2a9a0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000216f1b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fe808b2a9a0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217fb60 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b61880'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fe808b2a9a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021777a0 UIView:0x7fe80893f840.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x7fe808939a90.trailing   (active)>
```

Comment: It's a bug on Apple's side. Constraints are how you lay out views in UIKit. SwiftUI's `NavigationView` has some connection to `UINavigationBar`, which has some constraint bug. You can probably ignore it.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to silence these?

Comment: @elyakshaver If caused by `NavigationView`, add a `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the end

Comment: @George awesome, I'll give this a try. Thank you!